# Call function on attachment creation from front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to redirect a user upon uploading file from front end. As uploading creates an attachment, so i am looking to find a hook - which call a function upon uploading a file. I have used [`add_attachment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_attachment) but its not working for me.

```
function redirect_user_on_upload(){
  wp_redirect('http://stackoverflow.com/');
}
do_action("add_attachment","redirect_user_on_upload");
```

Comment: You can't redirect from the `add_attachment` action, best option is to redirect user in the success response of your ajax call.

Comment: Hi Dani, what plugin or function are you using to upload the file from the frontend?

Comment: I am not using any plugin. Doing it manually.